# Kernel Backport for Debian Jessie?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, backports

I installed the 32 bit version of Debian Jessie (8.0) on an [Asus X205TA](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA). The [Asus X205TA](http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/) laptop is quirky like a lot of Intel Baytrail Atom laptops/tablets in that it has 32 bit EFI but a 64 bit capable CPU, and installing Linux on them is an exercise in frustration. Jessie is probably the first distro to support 32bit EFI out of the box, and the install went surprisingly smoothly. [As expected](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA) the sound and built in WIFI does not work, but everything else seems to work well.

I spent half a day compiling the 4.03 kernel but it crashes on boot, and I ended uninstalling it in frustration.

Is there any backport of the 4.0 (or 4.1 which is currently a release candidate) for Jessie? Debian also seems to have pulled the kernel image off of their ["experimental" repository](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/kernel/).

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 4.0.2 is available in [Debian unstable](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/linux). It can be installed on Jessie. If it doesn't work on your laptop, please report a bug (`reportbug linux-4.0.0-1-686-pae` if you're using the 32-bit version, or `reportbug linux-4.0.0-1-amd64` if you're using the 64-bit version).

Comment: Genuine question: how is this different (if at all) from installing the backported kernel from jessie-backports? That is, adding `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and using `apt-cache search linux-image` to find the latest version in the backports repo? Maybe in the end it's the same if the same version of the kernel gets installed.

Comment: @MichaelA it's no different, in fact installing from backports is better — but when I answered the question there was no 4.0 or later kernel in backports.